# LINQ2SQL Entities - Updating only the fields that have changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I was hoping there was an easier way to do this in my MVC 3 project.  In my database, I have a Customer table that is mapped in my application via LINQ2SQL.  There is also a partial customer class where I perform updates, look-up etc - which where I have an update method like this:

```
public static void Update(Customer customer)
{
    if (customer == null)
        return;

    using(var db = new DataBaseContext)
    {
        var newCustomer = db.Customers.Where(c => c.customer_id = customer.customer_id).SingleOrDefault();

        if(newCustomer == null) 
            return;

        newCustomer.first_nm = customer.first_nm;
        // ...
        // ...  Lot's of fields to update
        // ...
        newCustomer.phone_num = customer.phone_nm;

        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

What I was hoping to find was a less-cumbersome method to update the fields in newCustomer with the corresponding fields in customer that are different.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can implement [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx):

```
public class Customer
{
    public string first_nm { get; set; }
    public int phone_num { get; set; }
}        
class CustomerComparer : IEqualityComparer<Customer>
{
    public bool Equals(Customer x, Customer y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the customer' properties are equal.
        return x.first_nm  == y.first_nm && x.phone_num == y.phone_num ;
    }
}
```

<del>and do it as follows:</del>

```
if (newCustomer != customer)
{
    myDbContext.Customers.Attach(customer,true); // true means modified.
}
```

Or implement `ICloneable` and set `newCustomer` to `customer.Clone()`. then there's no need to attach `customer` since `newCustomer` is already attached.

in EF(4.1), I think You just have to attach the entity as modified:

```
  myDbContext.Customers.AttachAsModified(customer, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(customer), myContext);
```

**UPDATE:**
Well, it seems like L2S needs original values of the entity. In reply to your comment, you have a couple choices: Using a timestamp column, returning a subset of entities, or having the original entity in your hand. In your scenario, you have the original entity already:

```
// This is your original entity
var newCustomer = db.Customers.Where(c => c.customer_id = customer.customer_id).SingleOrDefault();
```

So you will most probably can do:

```
if (customer != newCustomer)
{
     myDbContext.Customers.Attach(customer, newCustomer);
}
```

Note: I'd rename `newCustomer` to `originalCustomer` if I were you since it's more related to the entity's state.

The problem with this approach is that you have an extra trip to database to get your original customer (`newCustomer` in your code). Take a look at [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2008/05/17/122222.aspx), [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2007/12/17/117791.aspx) and definitely [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb546187%28VS.90%29.aspx) to see how you can use TimeStamp columns to prevent the extra database trip.

Comment: My code gets to the attach method but fails, returning a "An entity can only be attached as modified without original state if it declares a version member or does not have an update check policy." error